# How to get limited number of message using Java Mail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using this code for loading inbox messages.

```
// connect to my pop3 inbox
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
Store store = null;
try {
    store = session.getStore("pop3");

    store.connect(inboxAccountConfiguration.getServerAddress(), inboxAccountConfiguration.getUserName(), inboxAccountConfiguration.getPassword());
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    // get the list of inbox messages
    Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

    if (messages.length == 0) System.out.println("No messages found.");

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        // stop after listing ten messages
        if (i > 10) {
            System.exit(0);
            inbox.close(true);
            store.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Message " + (i + 1));
        System.out.println("From : " + messages[i].getFrom()[0]);
        System.out.println("Subject : " + messages[i].getSubject());
        System.out.println("Sent Date : " + messages[i].getSentDate());
        System.out.println();
    }

    inbox.close(true);
    store.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However I need to limit number of messages to load

I have already tried something like that

```
Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages(0, (int) configuration.getNumber());
```

But this doesn't work, just throws an exception

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.getMessage(POP3Folder.java:364)
    at javax.mail.Folder.getMessages(Folder.java:933)
    at core.mail.POPMessageRetriever.lambda$getInboxMail$0(POPMessageRetriever.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How can I load only specific number of inbox messages?

Answer (score 1):

Messages are numbered starting at 1, not 0.

The getMessages method does not load any messages.  It only creates a Message object that acts as a reference to the message on the server.  The message data is only loaded when needed by one of the methods on the Message object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however this returns old messages instead of the latest ones, how can I get the most recent messages ?

Comment: This question is answered in the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#newmsgs).  The [com.sun.mail.pop3 package javadocs](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html) discuss approaches to this problem.